# Is it possible to Count by diffrent condition in one query?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a `Shipments` table which basicly contains Shipments data with dates

id is `integer`
dateshipped is `date`

```
id    dateshipped
1     1-JAN-16
2     1-JAN-16
3     3-FEB-16
4     9-FEB-16
```

I want to write a query which count all shipments based on Months.
What I should get is:

```
Jan  Feb  March....
2     2     0
```

I know I can do it by having query for each column, get only relevent rows for this specific month and just count them.

As follows:

```
Select     (Select count(*)
           from Shipments
           Where EXTRACT(YEAR FROM dateshipped)::int=2016 and EXTRACT(MONTH FROM dateshipped)::int=1 )as JAN,
           (Select count(*)
           from Shipments
           Where EXTRACT(YEAR FROM dateshipped)::int=2016 and EXTRACT(MONTH FROM dateshipped)::int=2 )as FEB
```

**This works however its too much of the same code...**

I am wondring if it is possible to do it with a single `FROM` statment and each column get it's own relevent rows for count.

Something like:

```
Select COL1,COL2,COL3...
from Shipments
Where EXTRACT(YEAR FROM dateshipped)::int=2016;
```

and have something like:

```
COL1 = count only JAN records
COL2 = count only FEB records
....
```

maybe there is something with `Parations` on months or any other solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a pivot query to accomplish this:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM dateshipped)::int = 1  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Jan,
       SUM(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM dateshipped)::int = 2  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Feb,
       SUM(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM dateshipped)::int = 3  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Mar,
       SUM(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM dateshipped)::int = 4  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Apr,
       SUM(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM dateshipped)::int = 5  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS May,
       SUM(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM dateshipped)::int = 6  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Jun,
       SUM(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM dateshipped)::int = 7  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Jul,
       SUM(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM dateshipped)::int = 8  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Aug,
       SUM(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM dateshipped)::int = 9  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Sep,
       SUM(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM dateshipped)::int = 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Oct,
       SUM(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM dateshipped)::int = 11 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Nov,
       SUM(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM dateshipped)::int = 12 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Dec
FROM Shipments
WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM dateshipped)::int=2016
```

Comment: Why do you need group by

Comment: You don't need `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 3):

Since 9.4 you can use [FILTER](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html)

```
SELECT
    count(*) AS total,
    count(*) FILTER (WHERE Extract(MONTH FROM dateshipped)::int=1) AS JAN,
    count(*) FILTER (WHERE Extract(MONTH FROM dateshipped)::int=2) AS FEB,
    ...
FROM Shipments
WHERE Extract(YEAR FROM dateshipped)::int=2016;
```

Comment: @java It should be slightly faster, however the effects are not all that significant. Though it's more db-friendly so I think it hope perform much better in further versions.

Answer (score 2):

Try case with sum function:

```
Select 
   sum(case when extract(MONTH from dateshipped)=1 then 1 else 0 end) as jan,
   sum(case when extract(MONTH from dateshipped)=2 then 1 else 0 end) as feb,
   sum(case when extract(MONTH from dateshipped)=3 then 1 else 0 end) as march
   .....
   .....
from Shipments
Where EXTRACT(YEAR FROM dateshipped)::int=2016;
```