# The best way to keep count data in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate

I need to create a statistic for some aggragete date splitted by days. 
For example:

```
select 
      (select count(*) from bananas) as bananas_count, 
      (select count(*) from apples) as apples_count, 
      (select count(*) from bananas where color = 'yellow') as  yellow_bananas_count;
```

obviously I will get:

```
bananas_count | apples_count     | yellow_bananas_count
--------------+------------------+ ---------------------
           123|              321 |                    15
```

but I need to get that data grouped by day, we need to know how many banaras we had yesterday.

The first thought which I got is create aview, but in that case i will not be able split by dates ( or I don't know how to do it).

I need a performance-wise database sided implementation of this task.

Comment: Need DDL of the table.

Comment: Something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35311022/1104979)?